# PHP HTML Sorting/Pagination/Search without jQuery or JS

Tags: php, html, sorting, pagination

I have a form in a php file as given below (I have designed it as a Table in my code but showing only the form here so that I can explain my current problem):

The following code is for **Searching**

```
echo '<form id="stat_form">
          <input form="stat_form" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter search term"  onfocus="this.placeholder = \'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Enter search term\'">
          <input form="stat_form" type="submit" value="Search" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
    </form>';
```

After some more operations, the following is added to the code for **Sorting**(used as the table headers) in which $title1 and $title2 are different from the corresponding Button values(Hence used < button> instead of < input>):

```
      echo '<button form="stat_form" name="sort" value="Name" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">'.$title1.'</button>
            <button form="stat_form" name="sort" value="Address" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">'.$title2.'</button>';
```

And finally after few more functions the following is added for **Pagination**. $prev_page, $curr_page and $next_page are calculated in my code:

```
      echo '<button form="stat_form" name="page" value="'.$prev_page.'" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"'.($prev_page==$curr_page?" disabled":"").'>Prev</button>
      <button disabled>'.$curr_page.'</button>
      <button form="stat_form" name="page" value="'.$next_page.'" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"'.($next_page==$curr_page?" disabled":"").'>Next</button>';
```

Now my problem is(Assuming that I have already entered the Search string):

- When I click on Next / Prev buttons for pagination, the "sort" values are not being sent by the form
- When I click on $title1 / $title2 for Sorting then the "page" value is not being sent

According to the code that I have explained above, I would like to send 3 different values from the form at all times: "search", "sort", and "page"
How can I establish this?

Kindly do not suggest to use any library or external tool. Currently I wont be able to include any into my code.

Also since it is my first post in the forum, I am not sure if I have made my question clear. Kindly let me know so that I can explain further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you echoing this HTML?

Comment: Yes sorry about the "" quotation marks. I realised that only now

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, kindly let me know why it has been done so. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking around for the solution for the whole day but not able to get a satisfactoy answer. Hence using a work around here. I will post it here in case it will help others:

The only modification was in the pagination. I have removed it from the form and used it as a normal link. The drawback will be that when I do a sort, the page value is reset. Since it does not affect my project. I am inclined to use this solution.

```
  echo '<a href="'.$prev_page_url.'"><button class="buttons"'.($prev_page==$curr_page?" disabled":"").'>Prev</button></a>
        <button disabled>'.$curr_page.'</button>
        <a href="'.$next_page_url.'"><button class="buttons"'.($next_page==$curr_page?" disabled":"").'>Next</button></a>';
```

In the above code, 
$prev_page_url and $nextpage_url were calculated as

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].http_build_query(<search/sort/page parameters>)
```